# Xcopy a .txt over the network and add a date

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I'm trying to take a .txt file and move it over the network with `xcopy`.

Here is my code thus far:

```
@ECHO off
XCOPY /y pushd \\Oafrpnbtcsi01\Test_Systemplatz\Systemplatz_SLOT_1_Fail.txt

rem get date, make if file name friendly
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%i-%%j-%%k-%%l

set MBD=Systemplatz_SLOT_1_FailB%d%DN.txt
ren Systemplatz_SLOT_1_Fail.txt %MBD%
move *.txt F:\Public\Logfiles\Systemplatz\Test\02\Systemplatz Slot 1
@ECHO on
```

I also want the date to be added into the text file's name.

So far it's not working, so I'm positive I have done something wrong. If there is a better way to do this, please do explain.

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample of the txt file and the corresponding converted csv file.

Comment: @DavidPostill added a sample.

Comment: And the equivalent csv file?

Comment: Give me a few to Recompile my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems. First, there's this line:

```
XCOPY /y pushd \\Oafrpnbtcsi01\Test_Systemplatz\Systemplatz_SLOT_1_Fail.txt
```

`pushd` is a command in and of itself; it can't be passed as an argument to `xcopy`. `xcopy` needs two arguments, a source and a destination; it looks like you only have one. I'm guessing - but I am not sure - that you wanted to move the current directory to `\\Oafrpnbtcsi01\Test_Systemplatz\`, which contains the file you're going to work with. To do that, replace the above line with just this:

```
pushd \\Oafrpnbtcsi01\Test_Systemplatz\
```

The second issue is on this line:

```
move *.txt F:\Public\Logfiles\Systemplatz\Test\02\Systemplatz Slot 1
```

It looks like one of the folders in the path is called `Systemplatz Slot 1`, but to `move`, `Slot` and `1` look like different arguments because there are spaces. You should enclose the whole destination path in quotes, like this:

```
move *.txt "F:\Public\Logfiles\Systemplatz\Test\02\Systemplatz Slot 1"
```

Finally, you probably want a `popd` at the end of the script to reverse the `pushd`, taking the current directory back to its original place.

Comment: Awesome thank you was driving me nuts last night.